# Turning an object to a string using native javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have defined the following object:

```
let myObj = {
my: 'name',
is: 'Inigo Montoya',
prepare: 'to die!'
}
```

What is the best way of making myObj to equal { "my name is Inigo Montoya prepare to die!" }?

I know you can Stringify using JSON, but I'd like doing it in native Javascript. I've tried the following to get a string made of all the object properties + values:

```js
let combined = Object.entries(obj).forEach(entire => {
  return `${entrie[0]} ${entrie[1]}` });
```

but I only get undefined.

I'd love understanding why I'm getting undefined in this particular case, and also hearing what would you say the best way to solve the problem described above. Thanks!!

Comment: `.forEach` always returns `undefined`, you probably want `.map()`

Comment: forEach does not make any sense since return does nothing....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't return from a forEach, rather `map` to an array of the returned paired strings, then join that to one string:

```
Object.entries(obj).map(entry => `${entry[0]} ${entry[1]}`).join(" ");
```

Or I'd just do

```
Object.entries(obj).flat().join(" ")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the clean solutions! marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

forEach returns `undefined`. You can use [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let myObj = {my: 'name',is: 'Inigo Montoya',prepare: 'to die!'}

let string = Object.entries(myObj)
             .reduce((op,[key,value])=>op+= ' '+ key + ' '+ value, '')
             .trim()

console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `String constructor` convert the `object` into a `string` and using `split` and `join` remove `:` and `,`

```js
let myObj = {
my: 'name',
is: 'Inigo Montoya',
prepare: 'to die!'
}
console.log(String(JSON.stringify(myObj)).split(':').join(" ").split(',').join(' ').split(`"`).join(''))
```

Comment: I literally said I know I can use JSON stringify but I want to do it with native Javascript only :|

Answer (score 1):

```js
let myObj = {
  my: 'name',
  is: 'Inigo Montoya',
  prepare: 'to die!'
}

const res = Object.entries(myObj).map(el => el[0].concat(" " + el[1])).join(" ")


console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` because `forEach()` always returns `undefined`

```js
let myObj = {
  my: 'name',
  is: 'Inigo Montoya',
  prepare: 'to die!'
}

let combined = Object.entries(myObj).reduce((ac,entrie)=> ac  + ` ${entrie[0]} ${entrie[1]} ` ,'').trim();;
  console.log(combined)
```

Comment: Don't know why it got downvoted but I upvoted this one. I liked the reduce approach a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myObj = {
  my: 'name',
  is: 'Inigo Montoya',
  prepare: 'to die!'
}

var the_keys = Object.keys(myObj),
  length = the_keys.length,
  resArray = new Array(length);
  
while (length--) {
  resArray[length] = [the_keys[length], myObj[the_keys[length]]];
}
var myStr = resArray.join(" ").replace(/,/g, ' ');
console.log(myStr);
```

This answer will accommodate those who have an [older browser that does not support `Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill). The code sets three variables: **the_keys** assigned the result of passing `myObj` to `Object.keys()`, **length** gets assigned the length property of that array, **resArray** results from creating a new array, using the **length** variable to set it.  Then the **resArray** is iteratively filled with an array containing each key and its corresponding value. The variable **myStr** results from joining the values of **resArray** with blank space and [replacing](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) all commas with a blank space.